# How to install a 2nd theme onto one that you've already installed? Issues with relative resource links

Tags: javascript, gatsby, gatsby-image, gatsby-plugin, gatsby-plugin-feed

I have just tried to install a second theme onto my present gatsby install, following the steps outlined within the Multiple Themes tutorial. I am having some trouble with the linking of resources for the new theme. Because it lives within node_modules, I would guess that this is where it should be referencing. At present, it seems to be trying to reference the main src directory for the first theme.

Not sure what exactly I am doing wrong here. Here is a copy of my gatsby-config for reference, specifically the plugins section:

```
plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `gatsby-mytheme-tailwind`,
        short_name: `mytheme-main`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: fullConfig.theme.colors.white,
        theme_color: fullConfig.theme.colors.blue["400"],
        display: `minimal-ui`,
        icon: `src/images/MyTheme-Icon.png`,
      },
    },
    //Custom Themes
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-tailwind-simplicity-theme`,
      options: {
        basePath: `/simplicity-itself`,
      },
    },
    //Rest of the plugins
    `gatsby-plugin-eslint`,
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    `gatsby-plugin-root-import`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-postcss`,
      options: {
        postCssPlugins: [
          require(`tailwindcss`)(tailwindConfig),
          require(`autoprefixer`),
          ...(process.env.NODE_ENV === `production`
            ? [require(`cssnano`)]
            : []),
        ],
      },
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-offline`,
  ]
```